# Regression using residuals

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, residuals

My question is regarding OLS regression and their residuals.

If we have a model:

$$Y = B_0 + X_1B_1 + X_2B_2 + X_3B_3 + e$$

Where Y = Independent variable, X_i = Dependent variabels, B_i are the OLS Estimates and e = residuals.

If we were to take the residuals from that question and use it as our new independent variable in the same regression:

$$e = B_0 + X_1B_1 + X_2B_2 + X_3B_3 + r$$

Where e = Independent variable, X_i = Dependent variabels, B_i are the OLS Estimates and r = residuals.

Questions:

1)What is the purpose of doing such a procedure? What information can we gather from the second regression?

2)If the first regression gives us statistical significant estimations but the second one doesn't? Does this tell us anything about col linearity?

Thank you, please ask if something was unclear.

Answer (score 4):

You would not do that. The second model contains no information whatsoever.

You can think of $e$ as a version of $y$ with the influence of $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ removed. So it is trivial that $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ have no linear effect on $e$, that is just how $e$ was created. So the coefficients will be 0 (up to numerical precision), the $R^2$ will be 0, and the $p$-values 1. This is not an empirical result; it is just a consequence of how $e$ was generated. If says nothing about collinearity (or anything else for that matter).

Comment: Hm okej, the thing is I have a question where i am suppose to do so and compare the R^2 between them and show what MLR assumption is not fulfilled..

Comment: Either you are misunderstanding the question, or there is an error in that question. That is now up to you. You have received a hint that your current understanding of the question is incorrect and why. Giving you more would imperil your learning experience.

Comment: I would like to add as a small comment that it is often seen that the second equation (i.e. the one with the fitted residuals as) is done with squared residuals in order to test for heteroscedasticity.

Comment: @MichaelL. I am under the impression that the X's are not used as inputs in the second equation when testing for heteroscedasticity as there may be lag structures if time series analysis is in play. ..What is your source for your understanding ?

Comment: @IrishStat. So my comment refers to the Breusch-Pagan test (or its extension the white test). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breusch%E2%80%93Pagan_test. But you may be right that this does not work proper for time series.